# How to use Google Sign in with Realm Mobile Platform

Tags: ios, swift, realm, google-signin, realm-mobile-platform

I am building a product based on Realm and Realm Mobile Platform. I have authenticated users using the [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) I use the following to log in my user to Realm Mobile Platform

```
extension ApplicationDelegate:GIDSignInDelegate{
    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    let credential = SyncCredentials.google(token: signIn.currentUser.authentication.accessToken)
    SyncUser.logIn(with: credential, server: authUrl()) { [weak self](user, error) in

        if let user = user {
            debugPrint("Signed in!")
        } else if let error = error as? NSError {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            //Prints "The provided credentials are invalid"
        }
    }
}
```

There is a signed in Google User, but the response is always "The provided credentials are invalid", which is not very helpful. Any ideas? Has anyone gotten Google Sign in to work on Realm Mobile Platform?

Comment: Did you setup ObjectServer for Google Authentication? Please lear more here: https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#authentication

Comment: Yes, I have added the Google Client Id for my app. There is not much info on what type of credential that is needed for realm though. Web Application, Service Account.. there are many ways to create credentials and the Realm Documentations give no guidance in what you should use. For a service account(server to server) a client secret would be needed, but there is no mention of this in the Realm Examples. I used the Web Application Oauth Client Credentials, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: sorry for a delay with reply but I've just noticed that you use `signIn.currentUser.authentication.accessToken` instead of `user.authentication.idToken` as suggested in Google's docs. Also if you found an issue could you please share what it was related to, thanks!

Comment: I am facing same issue. I tried with both idToken and accessToken but none of these working. I had also setup auth provider in server but still it is not working . Hey guys do you find any soluations ?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you're using the correct token property from google.

The token you need to use to authenticate is

```
user.authentication.idToken
```

and not

```
signIn.currentUser.authentication.accessToken
```

the correct extension would be:

```
extension ApplicationDelegate:GIDSignInDelegate{
    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    let credential = SyncCredentials.google(token: user.authentication.idToken)
    SyncUser.logIn(with: credential, server: authUrl()) { [weak self](user, error) in

        if let user = user {
            debugPrint("Signed in!")
        } else if let error = error as? NSError {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            //Prints "The provided credentials are invalid"
         }
     }
 }
```